# How to reload partial pages in Rails using RJS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rjs

Hi Currently i am working on a rails project . where i have to reload a partial page .

For example  Create action

```
 def create
    # Some transaction to the database 
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html {render :text => 'Add post' }
     format.js
   end
  end
```

In my views  posts/create.js.rjs   i would like to reload the users/_login.html.erb  file 
   This contains the total number of posts  or the post's size , when it creates a new post its should reload the partial page _login.html.erb and display the posts incremented size

In create.js.rjs  if i use `page.reload`  it reloads the entire page  , How to reload only the partial file _login.html.erb inside create.js.rjs .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code will look like:

```
  page.replace_html "login-block-id", :partial => "users/login"
```

Where login-block-id is the id of element that wraps your login template

Note that `replace_html` can accept the same arguments as render do.

Answer (score 2):

Yo could also try

```
page[:my_div].replace :partial => "/users/login"
```

where my_div is the id of element that wraps your login template